# Transpose duplicated rows to column in R

Tags: r, duplicates, plyr, reshape

I have a large data.frame (20000+ entries) in this format:

```
id  D1      D2
1   0.40    0.21
1   0.00    0.00
1   0.53    0.20
2   0.17    0.17
2   0.25    0.25
2   0.55    0.43
```

Where each id may be duplicated 3-20 times. I would like to merge the duplicated rows into new columns, so my new data.frame looks like:

```
id  D1      D2      D3      D4      D5      D6
1   0.40    0.21    0.00    0.00    0.53    0.20
2   0.17    0.17    0.25    0.25    0.55    0.43
```

I've manipulated data.frames before with plyr, but I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The best option would be to just use `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2". But before we jump to that option, let's see what else we have available to us:

---

You mention that the number of rows per "id" is unbalanced. That would make it somewhat difficult to put into a tidy rectangular `data.frame`.

Here are a few examples.

#### Balanced data: Three rows per "id"

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
                       D1 = c(0.4, 0, 0.53, 0.17, 0.25, 0.55), 
                       D2 = c(0.21, 0, 0.2, 0.17, 0.25, 0.43)), 
                  .Names = c("id", "D1", "D2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
                  class = "data.frame")
mydf
#   id   D1   D2
# 1  1 0.40 0.21
# 2  1 0.00 0.00
# 3  1 0.53 0.20
# 4  2 0.17 0.17
# 5  2 0.25 0.25
# 6  2 0.55 0.43
```

With such data, you can just use `aggregate`:

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ id, mydf, as.vector))
#   id D1.1 D1.2 D1.3 D2.1 D2.2 D2.3
# 1  1 0.40 0.00 0.53 0.21 0.00 0.20
# 2  2 0.17 0.25 0.55 0.17 0.25 0.43
```

#### Unbalanced data: Some workarounds

If you've added a fourth value for "id = 2", `aggregate` won't work here:

```
mydf[7, ] <- c(2, .44, .33)
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ id, mydf, as.vector))
# Error in data.frame(`0` = c(0.4, 0, 0.53), `1` = c(0.17, 0.25, 0.55, 0.44 : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 4
```

It might be best to just have a `list` of the resulting `vector`s:

```
lapply(split(mydf[-1], mydf[[1]]), function(x) unlist(x, use.names=FALSE))
# $`1`
# [1] 0.40 0.00 0.53 0.21 0.00 0.20
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 0.17 0.25 0.55 0.44 0.17 0.25 0.43 0.33
#
```

Or, if you insist on a rectangular `data.frame`, explore one of the several tools to `rbind` unbalanced data, for example, `rbind.fill` from "plyr":

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(lapply(split(mydf[-1], mydf[[1]]), 
                  function(x) data.frame(t(unlist(x, use.names=FALSE)))))
#     X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8
# 1 0.40 0.00 0.53 0.21 0.00 0.20   NA   NA
# 2 0.17 0.25 0.55 0.44 0.17 0.25 0.43 0.33
```

---

#### Unbalanced data: A more direct approach

Alternatively, you can use `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2" as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
x <- melt(mydf, id.vars = "id")
## ^^ That's not enough information for `dcast`
##    We need a "time" variable too, so use `ave`
##      to create one according to the number of
##      values per ID.
x$time <- ave(x$id, x$id, FUN = seq_along)
## ^^ I would probably actually stop at this point.
##    Long data with proper ID and "time" values
##      tend to be easier to work with and many
##      other functions in R work more nicely with
##      this long data format.
dcast(x, id ~ time, value.var = "value")
#   id    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
# 1  1 0.40 0.00 0.53 0.21 0.00 0.20   NA   NA
# 2  2 0.17 0.25 0.55 0.44 0.17 0.25 0.43 0.33
```