# Turn two-column dataframe with duplicate identifiers from long to wide, preserving scores

Tags: r, casting, reshape, tidyr, melt

## The problem and the desired outcome

I've got a data set like the toy data here:

```
mydf<-   data.frame(
id = c("AB","AB","AB","BB","BB","CD","CD","CD","CD","ED"),
score = c(4,2,1,2,2,1,5,6,3,5))
```

And what I'd like to end up with as a data frame or table in the following format, where the column heading labels are somewhat arbitrary:

```
new.df <- data.frame(
id = c("AB", "BB", "CD","ED"),  
score1 = c(4,2,1,5), 
score2 = c(2,2,5,NA), 
score3 = c(1,NA,6,NA), 
score4 = c(NA,NA,3,NA)
)
```

The desired data frame "collapses" over *id* and preserves each *score* (i.e, I'm not trying to compute sums or averages. It seems as though the fact that there are duplicate entries in *id* is one reason why I'm not having much luck.

## What I've tried:

1. Using `Reshape`
   Following a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r).

   ```
   library(reshape)
   new.df1<-
   reshape(mydf, idvar = "id", timevar = "score", direction = "wide")
   View(new.df2)

   #Warning message:
   #In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,     :multiple rows match for score=2: first taken
   ```
2. `reshape` again

   ```
   new.df2<-cast(mydf, score ~  id)
   #Using score as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
   #Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
   #  undefined columns selected
   ```

3.Using 'tidyr'

Following a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format-r).

```
  library(tidyr)
  new.df2 <- spread(mydf, key = id, value = score)
  #Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9)
```

4. And `tidyr` from a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960394/unexpected-behavior-with-tidyr)

   ```
   mydf$row <- 1:nrow(mydf) ## added explicit row numbers
   my.df4 <- 
     mydf %>%
     gather(vars, val, -id, -row )

   my.df4<-  spread(my.df4, val, vars)
   ```
5. Using 'melt' and 'reshape'

From a great question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894228/transpose-duplicated-rows-to-column-in-r) that I couldn't get to work:

```
library(reshape2)
my.df5 <- melt(mydf, id.vars = "id")
my.df5$row <- ave(my.df5$id, my.df5$id, FUN = seq_along)
 # Warning messages:
  # 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:6) :
  # invalid factor level, NA generated
```

6. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417973/easy-way-to-convert-long-to-wide-format-with-counts-in-r) post didn't help either

I'd love any suggestions as to how to accomplish the desired data frame. Thanks everyone!

Comment: change `ave(my.df5$id, my.df5$id, FUN = seq_along)` to `ave(seq_along(my.df5$id), my.df5$id, FUN = seq_along)` and it should work. or use `reshape(mydf, dir = 'wide', idvar = 'id', timevar = 'row', v.names = 'score', sep = '')`